# How do you use a different theme in a remote VS Code window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Using VS Code Remote Development (SSH, container, WSL) I want a different theme on my remote and local VS Code windows so that I can easily tell them apart.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set your theme in remote settings to use a different theme for that specific remote, open up the command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run the "Open Remote Settings" command:

[image]

Then add the following setting and save:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "<your theme of choice>"
}
```

[image]

---

There is currently no way to do this all at once for all remotes, it must be configured per machine.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist anymore

Version: 1.74.3 (system setup)
Commit: 97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534
Date: 2023-01-09T16:59:02.252Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No

Comment: Yup, I can't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @DanielImms' answer, you can add the same setting to your `.vscode/settings.json` or your `.code-workspace` file to select a different color scheme for each (remote) folder or workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the top answer is applicable anymore, however this approach works.

1. Go to `Settings -> Workbench -> Appearance`
2. Pay attention to the tabs at the top which has `User`, and `Workspace`

   - You may have more option like `Remote [<server_name>]` if you are connected to your code via `ssh`
3. Modify the settings under the tab to get the desired result.

   - `User` means global default settings for vscode
   - `Remote` overrides global and takes effect to all specified remote sessions
   - `Workspace` takes highest precedence, and modifies only the settings for the current folder.